# Updating GMM to GaussianMixture min_covar parameter mismatch issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to update soon-to-be-deprecated scikit-learn calls in another package when I got stumped by the new way it instantiates the class and with the fact that there is no one-to-one mapping between old and new instantiation parameters.

Specifically the [old Gaussian Mixture Model class](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) had this instantiation call

```
class sklearn.mixture.GMM(n_components=1, covariance_type='diag', random_state=None, thresh=0.01, min_covar=0.001)
```

Meanwhile the [new Gaussian Mixture Model class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture) has this instantiation signature:

````
class sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=1, covariance_type=’full’, tol=0.001, reg_covar=1e-06, max_iter=100, n_init=1, init_params=’kmeans’, weights_init=None, means_init=None, precisions_init=None, random_state=None, warm_start=False, verbose=0, verbose_interval=10)```
````

From the [manual](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) I read read that

> min_covar : float, optional
>
> Floor on the diagonal of the covariance matrix to prevent over-fitting. 
>   Defaults to 1e-3.

I've found several opened issues on scikit-learn git (and other git repos that use scikit-learn) and understand certain differences such as no fixed weights anymore and `precissions` being inverse covariances. What I can't seem to track is what represents `min_covar` parameter in this new class?

In fact now I'm even confused about the exact purpose of `min_covar` parameter in the old class. I took the manual excerpt to meant that this is the minimal covariance value allowed on the diagonal of the covariance matrix but none of the parameters in the new class seem to imply that such a thing even happens.

So to re-iterate: what exactly did `min_covar` do in the old `GMM` class, is there an attribute in the new class `min_covar` maps to and if not how should I go about reproducing the effects of `min_covar` or is that completely deprecated as a feature?

Comment: The closest I found in the new version is `reg_covar`.

Comment: @VivekKumar I suspected as much, but the description, to me at least, does not imply the same action. Specifically `min_covar` seem to imply a lower limit while `reg_covar` seem to imply addition of that value to the diagonal so that if covariance goes bellow that number it gets bumped back up. In one case it's guaranteed you'll never go below the value, while in the other it wouldn't be. Since this is a covariance matrix there's nothing preventing from going negative? Negative would just imply inverse relationship, right? I'm no statistician so any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I just asked a statistician and they said that off diagonals can go negative but diagonals can't. So I'd wager `reg_covar` behaves exactly like `min_covar`.